# Automapper: Map an Enum to its [Description] attribute

Tags: automapper

I have a source object that looks like this:

```
private class SourceObject {
    public Enum1 EnumProp1 { get; set; }
    public Enum2 EnumProp2 { get; set; }
}
```

The enums are decorated with a custom `[Description]` attribute that provides a string representation, and I have an extension method `.GetDescription()` that returns it. How do I map these enum properties using that extension?

I'm trying to map to an object like this:

```
private class DestinationObject {
    public string Enum1Description { get; set; }
    public string Enum2Description { get; set; }
}
```

I think a custom formatter is my best bet, but I can't figure out how to add the formatter *and* specify which field to map from at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Argh, idiot moment. Didn't realize I could combine ForMember() and AddFormatter() like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceObject, DestinationObject>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Enum1Desc, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.EnumProp1))
    .ForMember(x => x.Enum1Desc, opt => opt.AddFormatter<EnumDescriptionFormatter>())
    .ForMember(x => x.Enum2Desc, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.EnumProp2))
    .ForMember(x => x.Enum2Desc, opt => opt.AddFormatter<EnumDescriptionFormatter>());
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Unless you need to map both, I'd also suggest just leaving the names the same, and just add the formatter.  It's less configuration that way.

Comment: That's generally the approach I take, unless I have a really good reason otherwise. This came out of some testing I was doing and wanted to make sure the hard case was at least _possible_. Thanks!